# How to push to git repo built into jbpm suite

Tags: git, jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

We have a Red Hat jboss bpm suite running in a docker container. We would like to be able to push to the git repo that is created inside the suite.

How can we go about doing this? Can we just open the port and push to it? How does the user access work, for instance is it possible to add an ssh public key?

I have not seen anything in the documentation for this but if we have missed it I would appreciate a link, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would want to expose port 8001 from docker to be able to push into your BPM suite. In the standalone.xml you would also like to set some system properties to allow SSH connections against BPM. This is my current configuration

```
<system-properties>
   <property name="org.kie.server.repo" value="${jboss.server.data.dir}"/>
   <property name="org.kie.example" value="true"/>
   <property name="org.jbpm.designer.perspective" value="full"/>
   <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.daemon.host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
   <property name="org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
   <property name="org.guvnor.m2repo.dir" value="/home/jboss/.m2/repository"/>
   <property name="designerdataobjects" value="false"/>
</system-properties>
```

then I have a remote against BPM "ssh://bpmUsername@localhost:8001/reponame". My docker is exposed on localhost but i guess there could be a docker IP there aswell.
I'm not sure how to set it up with a ssh public key...

cheers!